# Clean install of Scientific Python without reformatting the disk

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy, installation, anaconda

1st, the Disclaimer: I looked at numerous questions here, there is question about uninstalling all pip–installed, uninstalling matplotlib, moving to 3.5 from 2.7, –– but I didn't find an answer to my specific problem. Sorry if I didn't look hard enough.

Basically, my problem is I have a mess of different packages installed by different means at different times. Manifestations of this are:

1) I can import numpy from python but not from Jupyter notebook:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5a0bd626bb1d> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

ImportError: No module named numpy
```

2) I cannot import nltk:

```
...
File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

likely many more.

I recently uninstalled jupyter and anaconda, installed anaconda again, - this didn't help.

I cannot uninstall numpy / scipy , although I can use them (?!?):

```
>:~%python -c 'from numpy.random import rand; print rand()'
0.946167984715
>:~%pip uninstall numpy
Cannot uninstall requirement numpy, not installed
```

I have two versions of Python: 
2.7.11 under /usr/local/bin/ pointing to /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/python

2.7.10 under /usr/bin/ pointing to 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

-- although the default is 2.7.10 (numpy works with it), and I think 2.7.11 was added by Anaconda (incorrectly, because it doesn't see numpy).

Yesterday I uninstalled everything I could think of, then upgraded to a new version of Mac OS (10.12.2 Sierra),  and then re-installed anaconda – in vain.

I am close to reformatting the disk and starting from scratch.
Is there a better option?

Thank you! and sorry for so many details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly on a MAC but these are the things to try on windows and it is probably similar on MAC.

Start with a clean install of anaconda then try "where python" and "where jupyter" (it is "which" instead of "where" on linux). This tells you where it is looking for the executables. Both should be subfolders of anaconda. If they are not check your PATH variable.

Now start python or jupyter; import sys and try sys.path. That tells you where python is looking for stuff. It should look only in anaconda sub folders.

Comment: Thank you, but that's basically my problem (I guess). My default python 2.10 is under /System/Library/Frameworks; 2.11 was installed later by Anaconda (my guess), and the remaining question is: why didn't it do the right thing and how to fix it, - setting aside installing the OS on a reformatted disk?

Comment: No. Anaconda installs everything in the anaconda folder and changes your default path to point to that. It does not overwrite anything else. Your problem is that somewhere you have a configuration script that is changing the path back. For example in linux you have .bashrc script that runs when you open a terminal. You must have something like that on the MAC.

Comment: You could try first manually editing your path to make sure anaconda is first on the list. If it later reverts to System/Library/Frameworks; 2.11 then you must have a config script somewhere on your machine. Maybe you can search file contents to find System/Library/Frameworks; 2.11. That would tell you which config file

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what has helped but on top of removing all traces of numpy / nltk / anaconda / jupyter etc AND after brew uninstall python AND installing Anaconda under / has helped.